# Error connecting to GitLab with JGit

Tags: java, git, gitlab, jsch, jgit

I am trying to use JGit to read some tags from a repository on GitLab. I can clone the repository in bash, so I know that I have permissions and so on.

When I try to fetch the tags using JGit, I get the following error:

```
UnknownHostKey: gitlab.com. RSA key fingerprint is b6:03:0e:39:97:9e:d0:e7:24:ce:a3:77:3e:01:42:01
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:198)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: gitlab.com. RSA key fingerprint is b6:03:0e:39:97:9e:d0:e7:24:ce:a3:77:3e:01:42:01
```

This is unexpected since I have the following in `known_hosts`:

```
gitlab.com,52.167.219.168 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBFSMqzJeV9rUzU4kWitGjeR4PWSa29SPqJ1fVkhtj3Hw9xjLVXVYrU9QlYWrOLXBpQ6KWjbjTDTdDkoohFzgbEY=
```

- Does JGit read `known_hosts` by default?
- Is there a way to manually add GitLab as a known host to JGit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have an [ecdsa fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), instead of what JGit is looking for: SHA_RSA

Simply type:

```
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa gitlab.com >> known_hosts
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. So JGit *does* use `known_hosts`, my file was just misconfigured.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Not exactly misconfigured, but not fully configured ;)

Comment: Sorry, you answered so fast that it was within the time restriction and then I forgot! Have some karma :)

Comment: @sdgfsdh No problem! Thank you.